# Can the read-only notification bar contain a link to the tweet?

Tags: feature-request, read-only

Sometimes a Stack Exchange site is in maintenance  mode. A notification bar shows that:

[image: Read-only notification]

Can this notification also contain a link to the [StackStatus Tweet](https://twitter.com/StackStatus). Normally there are more infos to the maintenance reasons.

Comment: Nice suggestion. It'll be great if this is possible.

Comment: But there is no tweet there now to explain the read-only mode..

Comment: There's not always a tweet, and if this switch is flipped unplanned, someone is in a hell of a hurry to get things working. For planned stuff, folks are generally notified well in advance, and would have read the tweet (or blog).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [There is one short message](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/443399022012030976) on the tweet.

Comment: @juergend: that message only talks about web sockets, and predates the outage by some time. Nothing is said about read-only mode, which means that something *else* fell over here. It is a far cry from an actual explanation.

Comment: show the tweet if it is recent and has hashtag `#readOnlyMode`..

Comment: What about the heathens (me included) who don't use twitter?

Comment: You can include me in that list of heathens.  Doesn't Twitter get enough juice already?

Comment: Can we get some on hold music that plays via a midi file in the browser?

Comment: @Liam - You don't have to be signed up to twitter to click a link to a tweet.

Comment: @jonsca: And a blinking marquee.

Comment: @TimPost: I never read status blogs or tweets unless the site isn't working.

Comment: @juergend in which case you will see why (if it has been published) the site is in read only mode, no issue ;)