# Add Twitter status to StackOverflow maintenance page

Tags: feature-request, twitter, maintenance

The StackOverflow maintenance page states:

> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns
>   into an extended outage, we will **post details on the [status blog](https://www.stackstatus.net/)**.

[image: StackOverflow Offline]

Would it be worthwhile to add a latest tweet(s) from [@StackStaus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/) on this page as well?

As we saw today, the outage was short enough to not merit a blog post, but caused enough of an impact to post a tweet about.

It could be done either via the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) or using the embed code (as provided by Twitter):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/StackStatus" data-widget-id="443439711357370368">Tweets by @StackStatus</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

[image: StackStatus Twitter]

Comment: Related: [Can the read-only notification bar contain a link to the tweet?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224997)

Comment: And the same objections apply, only more so. When the 500 error message appears, the team is busy trying to fix the problem and not tweeting.

Comment: Would a link to https://twitter.com/stackstatus suffice?

Comment: Sure, a link would work too. I came to Meta to find a closed question of someone asking about the status, and a link to the tweet was a comment there. And thanks, @MartijnPieters, I didn't see that post in my initial search. I would argue that there probably isn't always going to be a tweet, but it is just another avenue for potential information. And hopefully like me, people who then go visit StackStatus will follow it, causing more awareness.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Perhaps even embed a [twitter timeline widget](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)? It's just JS and served from the Twitter.com servers, after all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can't disagree that something clientside is a good idea. Server-side is "out" for obvious reasons, but yes, it makes sense. That isn't a guarantee that it'll happen, but... it is hard to say "why not".

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yeah, I know, it'll still take some work to alter the template and make sure it fits with the design, etc. etc. etc. :-P So it will happen in 6 to 8 weeks, right?

Answer (score 15):

Adding a link sounds a very good idea, but very timely:

[image]

Evidence that we're not the only #fail ;p

Comment: We should just rename it #experience.  What you get just after you need it.

Comment: You broke Twitter so the minor SE outage would pale in comparison. Brilliant.

Comment: And we still choose to ignore Murphy!

Answer (score 7):

I think linking to the StackStatus Twitter account is a good idea, but I don't know if I'm in love with the idea of *embedding* the Twitter stream on the maintenance page. Our devs and SREs (rightfully) don't update Twitter the *instant* stuff goes down; seeing an out-of-date tweet is worse than seeing no additional information, in my opinion.

I'm afraid that if the stream was embedded on the page, there might be some rather...off-putting results.

What if you visited to find us offline and a tweet in your face that said "[And we're done, that's it for tonight](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/440301153893761024)"...not realizing you had hit the site 2 minutes after it went down and that tweet was from 10 days ago?

If you're clicking a link and making an active decision to look at the most recent tweets, there's a better chance you'll notice the time stamp from the last tweet than if you see the tweet embedded on the page.

Comment: Moreover, adding the twitter link would imply _forcing_ it to go down whenever SO is down.  Bad idea.

Comment: We could make it show only recent tweets, and if there are none recent leave it off.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I'd be okay with that, I think.