# Show StackStatus updates on readonly homepage

Tags: feature-request

Would it not be useful to show, or at least link to, the StackStatus Twitter feed on the read-only homepage, to indicate to people why the site is in read-only mode and how long it might be before it's back up?

Comment: Related - [Can the read-only notification bar contain a link to the tweet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224997/can-the-read-only-notification-bar-contain-a-link-to-the-tweet)

Comment: Fair enough. (15)